# Xcode 7.2 - during leaks instrumentation, app is not connecting to internet

Tags: ios, xcode

when I try to use leak instruments while profiling my app, for my sever request I get

400 Bad Request

However, if I run my app normally in debug mode then it works fine.

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you've several schemes and set difference URLs for your request.

Check your target's scheme setting, make sure your Profile's Build Configuration is the one you want. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

---

**Note**: As @PetahChristian pointed out in comment below, it's better to set Release mode for Profile, and figure out the reason why the URL is incorrect in release mode only, correct it then.

Comment: @user2384694 glad to help :)

Comment: If the app isn't connecting in Release mode, wouldn't it likely be unrelated to Instruments? Perhaps they should run the app in Release mode and determine why it's not connecting. That way, they would not have to profile `-Onone` code which the compiler hadn't optimized.

Comment: @PetahChristian good point, i've updated the answer w/ ur suggestion append, thx :)